# Web Socket failed during Handshake in SignalR application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to run my signalR application but i am getting the following error : "

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:60377/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=f8tOcpqdXVZ245%2BvWKsSFHaGfl6GePMtKf0Jk9wSIJQxsa5KnEiZFyGoFgYuwbQ%2FirsDjiX%2FHtVRJAvhvmOtrvYJpaZD21GHiyyqBw785nI2TICxJ4P33puQnEnjGSlMpmMBxtNk02XxkTJpZxvClw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22geologuehub%22%7D%5D&tid=4'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   500"

I would appreciate any help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the a list of fall-back transports on the javascript fixed the problem. it is weird because i am using googleChrome (Version 77.0.3865.90) and the web socket is not supported!!

```
  $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }).done(function ()
  {
       console.log(`SignalR connection transport used is "${$.connection.hub.transport.name}"`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when:

1. Your hub is not an public class.
2. Your server can't instantiate the hub.
3. You'r making an `https` connection when your server runs on `http` and vice-versa.

Comment: I have checked the first 2, except the last one, my server runs on http and i don't know if the browser would run on the https if the server is on http ?

Comment: Make sure how to do your request in the client side.

Comment: This is what the request URL: "ws://localhost:60377/signalr/connect?transport=" on the client side, i don't understand why is ws instead http!!?

Comment: what is exactly your client side? How you invoke the connection?

Comment: The problem was the connection transport, it is weird because i am using googleChrome (Version 77.0.3865.90) and the web socket is not supported

Comment: Its hard to help when you don't provide any code, but I'm glad that you resolved your problem!

Comment: Appreciate for your support mate!!